# PyCharm второе введённое значение считает пустым

Tags: python, pycharm

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой в PyCharm. При написании любого простейшего кода, где пользователю требуется вводить более одного значения, второе значение воспринимается пустым. Для примера код:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
s = x * y
print(s)
```

В любом интерпретаторе работает корректно, но в PyCharm почему-то после ввода двух значений выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oleg\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 2, in <module>
y = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Со временем понял, что он почему-то считает, будто второе значение вообще не было введено, хотя ввод осуществляется корректно. При этом, если запускать код не через кнопку "Run", а через "Debug", то всё работает нормально.

С чем такое может быть связано?

Comment: Олег, это связано с багом PyChаrm. Вы уже, наверное, 10й, кто приходит сюда с  этим вопросом, совершенно не пользуясь поиском по этому сайту (например, на "invalid literal for")  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Это [баг](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call) PyCharm. Ждем фикса.

А пока что в `Run | Edit Configurations` включить `Emulate terminal in output console` или `Run with python console` - смотря что сработает.